# Differential Equation: Determine $x''$ when $x'=xt^2+x^3+e^xt$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Determine $x''$ when $x'=xt^2+x^3+e^xt$

I haven't worked with DE's in a while...would the best approach be to use separation of variables?

Comment: Is $x$ a function of $t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $D$, or if you prefer $\frac{d}{dt}$ is a linear operator, we can do this piecewise. That is $D^2x = D(Dx) = D(xt^2 + x^3 + e^{x}t) = D(xt^2) + D(x^3) + D(e^{x}t)= (x'(t)\cdot t^2 + x(t)\cdot 2t) + ...$

I'll leave the other two terms for you to evaluate as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $x$ is a function of $t$, you don't need to solve the equation to determine $x''$. Instead take the derivative of $x'$ and use the chain rule, substituting for $x'$ when necessary.